# How to calculate force required to push down on a supported wooden cylinder (arrow shaft), a distance of exactly 12.7mm (0.5″)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, elasticity, statics

trying to find out how many newtons do I need to push down an arrow shaft a distance of 0.5″ in order to measure the spine factor.
the diameter of the wooden arrow is 7.9375mm (5/16")
stiff arrows require 1800g weight on them to bend them 0.5″.

assuming I am measuring the most stiff arrow, I need 1800g to push down vertically on it. how many newtons is that? in order to choose an appropriate linear actuator

the arrow is placed just like the picture attached with two supports, load cells are located on each support to measure the weight applied.

[image]

Comment: Incomplete question. The amount of force you need depends on the stiffness (as your question clearly states).

Comment: Yes you are right, let's assume I'm measuring the most stiff arrow, which requires 1800g of weight applied. how many newtons is that? or what equations do i need to use to select an appropriate motor. the motor i currently have has this specified in the data sheet: Max Force (lifted) 18N OR 45N. which one do I need?

Comment: Just convert 1800 g to Newtons (assuming earth's gravity). $F = 1.8kg \cdot 9.81m/s^2 = 17.66N$

Answer (score 1):

> assuming I am measuring the most stiff arrow, I need 1800g to push
> down vertically on it. how many newtons is that?

It's not clear, at least to me, exactly what you are trying to accomplish. But if it requires the weight of a 1.8 kg mass, then the force is $mg$ and equals 17.64 N given $g$ as 9.8 m/s$^2$.

Hope this helps.